# Facebook messenger platform, error while getting Thread Context

Tags: facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm getting an error with code `2018164` while trying to get the user's context from webview. The error code is `2018164`, but I can't find it in the documentation. Does anyone have any info on this ?

```
MessengerExtensions.getContext("MY APP ID",
          function success(result){
            THREAD_TYPE = result.thread_type;
            if(THREAD_TYPE == "USER_TO_PAGE"){
                share("broadcast");
            }
            else{
                share("current_thread");
            }
          },
          function error(err){
            alert("Failed to get thread_type : " + err + ". Doing a broadcast share");
            share("broadcast");
          }
        );
```

Comment: getting the same error, where you able to find what it means?

Comment: @fadz, nope. Still the same.

Comment: I was getting the error because i was using the wrong app_id in my code when i changed it everything worked fine

Comment: Good to know that its solved for you. Strangly, I'm getting this only in my test app and not in production.

Comment: @fadz is right, issue is the app_id. I was using the page_id instead of app id

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @fadz, @Shabin Muhammed and their "hints" I've found out what `app id` the docs are referring to:

It is the `app id` in your App dashboard on [Facebook Developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/).

**3/2018** - As of now this id is visible and situated in the top left corner of that page (as far as you have an app).

The error code `2018164` can be shown by appending the `err` parameter in the body of your page.

As per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/getContext), the following function retrieves additional information about the person and the thread that opened the `webview`:

```
MessengerExtensions.getContext('YOUR_APP_ID', 
   function success(thread_context){
     // success
   },
   function error(err){
     // error
   }
);
```

People tend to erroneously pass the `page_id` which is present in the body of each request that the `webhook` receives when sending messages to the bot for instance.

Comment: Here's also a link with that documents all the error codes: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/error-codes).